# Material UI React Modal Dialog on custom container

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to show a dialog that's only partially modal, as in modal over a specific element, so that the user can still interact with other parts of the application. The docs specify that a dialog component has a `container` and a `fullscreen` property. I've tried setting the `container` property to the div element I want to render the dialog and backdrop on. But without any luck.

[image]
I want to modal to only be modal on this part of the application as shown in the image.

Here are the docs for the Dialog component https://material-ui-next.com/api/dialog/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I literally just ran into this issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. It's not documented in the `<Dialog />` section, but if you look at the API [docs](https://material-ui-next.com/api/modal/) for the `<Modal />` component there is a prop called 'container' and since Dialog is really just a modified Modal component you're good to use the same props...

```
<Dialog
    container={() => document.getElementById('parentCo')}>
</Dialog>
```

Comment: I've tried this as well, and that didn't seem to have solved the issue. I don't think setting the `container` property is enough to make this happen, do you have a working sample?

Comment: In addition to setting the container property for the Modal, you need to alter the styles for both the Dialog and Backdrop. Add style={{position: 'absolute'}} and BackdropProps={{ style: { position: 'absolute' } }} to the Dialog. You'll also need to make sure the container element has its position set to relative.

Comment: @GretchenF. You da man! Actually for the backdrop styling (and for other children of the drawer), you can use `position:inherit`

Comment: Is there another way to pass in container component aside from using the document object? i.e. `document.getElementById('parentCo')`. Passing a React.Element does not seem to work. **Note**: I am using all function components in my app and no class components.