# How to display a modal inside a parent container

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, material-design, material-ui

I have a small sub-window like `div` in my app, and I need to display a modal inside the sub-window instead of the whole viewport.

So the backdrop of the modal should only cover the sub-window and not the entire screen

I am using material-ui, so any solution native to material-ui is preferred.

Comment: Any idea how it could work that you'd like to share? What have you achieved so far?

Comment: I think you need a mix also with styles, not only js problem. The ```div```have to be styled like "contained" in its parent and not full window.

Comment: You will need to play with CSS if you want to achieve that. I don't think material-ui provides a method to add a parent component to show a modal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `disablePortal` prop to `<Dialog>` and add styles as given in the code snippet

For some reason the styles applied to root didn't work through `classes` or `className` so had to add the `style` prop

```
import { makeStyles, DialogContent, Dialog } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  backdrop: {
    position: 'absolute',
  },
});

interface ISubWindow {
  onClose: () => void;
  open: boolean;
}

const SubWindow: React.FC<ISubWindow> = ({onClose, open}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Dialog
      disablePortal
      onClose={onClose}
      open={open}
      fullWidth
      className={classes.root}
      classes={{
        root: classes.root,
      }}
      BackdropProps={{
        classes: { root: classes.backdrop },
      }}
      style={{ position: 'absolute' }}
    >
      <DialogContent />
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default SubWindow;
```

Answer (score 2):

@Rahul's example got me most of the way, but it didn't quite work until I combined it with @Scott Sword and @Gretchen F. 's answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236761/material-ui-react-modal-dialog-on-custom-container#comment97682787_49245765) similar question.

The most important part was setting the `position` property of the parent div to `relative` though I also passed in props slightly differently which has worked a little easier for me:

```js
import { makeStyles, DialogContent, Dialog } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 'max-content',
    minHeight: '100%',
  },
  backdrop: {
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  paperScrollPaper: {
    overflow: 'visible',
  }
  });

interface ISubWindow {
  onClose: () => void;
  open: boolean;
}

const SubWindow: React.FC<ISubWindow> = ({onClose, open}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Dialog
      disableAutoFocus//disables rescrolling the window when the dialog is opened
      disableEnforceFocus//allows user to interact outside the dialog
      disableScrollLock//prevents the div from shrinking to make room for a scrollbar
      disablePortal
      onClose={onClose}
      open={open}
      fullWidth
      className={classes.root}
      classes={{
          paperScrollPaper: classes.paperScrollPaper
      }}
      BackdropProps={{
        classes: { root: classes.backdrop },
      }}
      style={{ position: 'absolute' }}
    >
      <DialogContent />
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default SubWindow;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```